# Python executable_path keyword no longer recognized when trying to launch chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using this code to  locate my web browser for the past months in a program that simply opens a web browser, and it has been successful  and all of a sudden this key word 'executable path' just shows up as red/not recognized.

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\inves\Desktop/chromedriver')